# Using a custom class (drawrect) on viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-graphics, xcode5

I am a noob with obj C, and I feel like I am doing everything right so please don't hate me for this ;)...I am trying to make a custom class that draws a rectangle onto a view controller.

So far I have made a class called 'Planet' with the drawrect code. I then added the Planet class (custom class tab) to a view controller on the storyboard. I get no errors but I also get no rectangle.

Planet.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface Planet : UIViewController
@end
```

Planet.m

```
#import "Planet.h"

@implementation Planet

-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
     CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 100);
     CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
     CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
     CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
     CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);
}

@end
```

And a screen of my view controller calling the Planet class.

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Outputs...

[image: No error]

Comment: Did you check whether it's called or not?

Comment: have you called it any where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIView` has `drawRect` method.Not `UIViewController`.

`UIViewController` and `UIView` both are subclasses of `UIResponder`. And `UIViewController` is not a subclass of `UIView`.
And `UIView` alone has drawRect method.so if you write drawRect in UIViewController, it just thinks its user defined function and won't call it.

If you still have doubt, **put a breakpoint in that drawRect function** and see whether it is called or not.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Planet being a subclass of `UIViewController`, make it a subclass of `UIView`. The add an instance of Planet to the view of the view controller, maybe in the `viewWillAppear` method, e.g.:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    Planet *myPlanet = [[Planet alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:myPlanet];
}
```

Comment: Bobnoble.. I like this approach. Attaching the class from the controller to its view. Thats exactly what I am trying to do in the long run. I tried your solution but got the error ..   no visible @interface for uiviewcontroller declares the selector 'viewwillappear' I also tried putting it in viewDidLoad with no luck.

Comment: Sorry about that - was too early in the morning and I forgot the `animated` parameter. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue just change the class in storyboard from Planet to what it was previously. Drag a UIView to the view controller and change class for that view to Planet.

You should avoid override of drawRect: if you don't need it because it's very expensive.
Instead you should use Layer. You can do something like that to draw rectangle with CALayer:

```
// Remember to import QuartzCore.h framework
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

CALayer *myLayer = [CALayer layer];
myRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 150.0f, 200.0f);
[myLayer setBounds:myRect];
[myLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[myLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
[myLayer setBorderWidth:1.0f];

//You can change radius
[myLayer setCornerRadius:15.0];
[self.layer addSublayer:myLayer];
```

It's much less expensive than drawRect:.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

in view will appear added subview as planet(UIView).